# Is my indexer working?

Tags: indexer

I've managed to import >200,000 SKUs and am now struggling to index them running the command line indexer.

It's basically running for more than 12 hours now and I don't even don't know if it's doing anything or not. I got 4 errors in the meantime telling me "The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size'". I've already found out that this has to do with the innodb_buffer_pool_size.

Is there any way to see if the process is still doing anything? Typing in php indexer.php --status gives me:

```
Product Attributes:                 Require Reindex
Product Prices:                     Require Reindex
Catalog URL Rewrites:               Running
Category Products:                  Require Reindex
Catalog Search Index:               Require Reindex
Stock Status:                       Pending
Tag Aggregation Data:               Pending
```

Also: Is it possible to show products on the Frontend without having the indexer run through everything? It's currently giving me a very old list of articles on one store and nothing on any of the 3 others.

One last thing: Is there any way to speed up the indexer? My "top" looks like there's much potential left because MySQL is only running at 1% CPU and 0.4% MEM. The PHP script isn't even listed.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to a reasonable `2G` - the indexer now runs within half an hour!

Comment: good job buddy :D